# How to establish that $\frac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}} \prod_{i=0}^k (t-x_i)^{n_i+1}=(n+1)!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

How to establish the following identity?

$$\frac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}} \prod_{i=0}^k (t-x_i)^{n_i+1}=(n+1)!$$

Where $n= k + n_0 + n_1 + ... + n_k$

Thanks.

Comment: What is the degree of the polynomial and the coefficient of the highest degree?

Comment: Expand the product to get $t^{n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k + k + 1} + \ldots = t^{n+1} + \ldots$. Now differentiating this $n+1$ times noting that $\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}t^m = 0$ for all $m<n+1$.